# jQuery: getting the value of a input field

Tags: jquery

This should be a no-brainer for you jQuery experts.

I have a form that has dynamically labeled field.

ex.

```
<input id="user_394783" type="hidden" value="3">
```

In my script, I have the ID of 394783 and I'm trying to attach it to "user_"

So, I'm trying this:

```
var userID = 394783;
$("#user_"+userID).val();
```

and

```
var userID = "user_"+ 394783;
$("#"+userID).val();
```

However this isn't working.  How do I concatenate values and have jQuery recognize my concatenation?

Thank you jQuery gods!

Comment: What's not working?  Are you getting errors? Both of those methods appear to be valid, so we'll need some more info to help.

Comment: remember to wait for the domready event

Comment: Are you assigning the result to anything?

Comment: Works here -- http://jsfiddle.net/hbulhoes/QbU4V/

Comment: I'll have to double check my code at work tomorrow.  But, thanks for the demo Humberto.

Comment: Yes, I'm assigning the value of the userID to a variable.  Again, I'll have to double check my code when I get back to the office.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those methods work: http://jsfiddle.net/my9vc/

Therefore, something else must be wrong. Check the following:

- Is the jQuery library loaded properly?
- When you try to get the value, does the field exist yet? In other words, are you waiting at least until the document is ready or loaded?
- Is there a bug elsewhere in your script that is preventing this code from running?

Answer (score 0):

```
var userID = 394783; 
userID += '';
$("#user_"+userID).val();
```

your value needs to be turned into a string. i had the very same problem.

Comment: The number is already being coerced to a string when you do this: `"#user_"+userID`. There's no need to concatenate it with an empty string beforehand.